# How to display the default image with all the post images in Facebook share

Tags: facebook, wordpress

While doing Facebook sharing, how do I display the default image (site logo) with all the post images in WordPress sites?

Also, I used the `Og:image` meta tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, according to the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

> You may include multiple og:image tags to associate multiple images
>   with your page.

You can test here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug